# Data sendo passada como NULL para o banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho essa estrutura:

```
//Dia atual + i meses 
$data_pagamento = "DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL ".$i." MONTH)";
$sql = "INSERT INTO pagamento(fk_1, fk_2, fk_3, fk_4, fk_5, preco, data_do_pagamento) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, $preco, $data_pagamento));
```

Se eu executo `SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL N MONTH)` a função me retorna a data atual mais N meses, porém no `insert` não está funcionando.

Depois do execute eu rodei o script `var_dump($stmt->debugDumpParams());`

Aonde deveria aparecer a string da `$data_pagamento` aparece:

> ```
> Key: Position #6:
> paramno=6
> name=[0] ""
> is_param=1
> param_type=2
> NULL
> ```

---

Alias, mesmo se eu executo direto no banco:

```
INSERT INTO pagamento(fk_1, fk_2, fk_3, fk_4, fk_5, preco, data_do_pagamento) 
VALUES 
(1,2,3,4,5,preco,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL N MONTH)
```

Ele funciona como deveria!

Comment: qual o tipo do campo data_do_pagamento, esta 'date', 'datetime' ? aparentemente esta tudo certo Marco

Comment: Você está tentando por uma string no campo. Não faz sentido tentar inserir "DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL ".$i." MONTH)"; no campo. Ou você faz isso no SQL, ou calcula no PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesta linha você está tentando colocar `$data_pagamento` no DB:

```
$stmt->execute(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, $preco, $data_pagamento));
```

Se é um campo data, a string tem que ser neste formato:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Mas você está tentando inserir essa *string*:

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Isto não é uma string no formato certo. E não faz sentido nenhum este valor para o SQL. Se quiser fazer o cálculo pelo SQL, deve informar na *query*:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pagamento(fk_1, fk_2, fk_3, fk_4, fk_5, preco, data_do_pagamento) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL ? MONTH))";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, $preco, $i));
```

Comment: Para entender melhor, troque o campo data por varchar, e vai entender melhor o que acontece. Vai estar escrito `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` literalmente no campo.

Comment: Pois é, eu cheguei a essa conclusão e a essa resposta poucos minutos depois de postar a pergunta, escolhida essa pergunta pelo simples fato de ter sido antes :)

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o `prepare` está fazendo o "escape" da string que você mandou. Com isso, acredito que o banco de dados esteja recebendo a query da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO pagamento(fk_1, fk_2, fk_3, fk_4, fk_5, preco, data_do_pagamento) 
VALUES 
("1","2","3","4","5","preco","DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL N MONTH)")
```

E aí quando ele tenta colocar a string `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL N MONTH)` na data, ela vira `NULL`.

Não conheço uma forma de fazer isso corretamente usando o `prepared statement`, mas a dica dada pelo @Bacco é boa. Você tentou isso?

Abs.